# How do I search for patterns in multiple arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, design-patterns

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [host] => google.com
        [type] => NS
        [target] => ns2.google.com
        [class] => IN [ttl] => 112756
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [host] => google.com
        [type] => NS
        [target] => ns1.google.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 112756
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [host] => google.com
        [type] => NS
        [target] => ns3.google.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 112756
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [host] => google.com
        [type] => NS
        [target] => ns4.google.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 112756
    )
)
```

I would like to search for the pattern `*google*`. Not sure what function to use to do this. in_array doesn't seem to like regex or searching multiple arrays.

Comment: What are you looking to return after you find this pattern?  The number of occurences of this pattern?  The keys of the arrays containing this pattern?  Or something else altogether?

Comment: Whether the pattern exist at all, true or false, boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use preg_grep:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function, which maps a callback (a function name, a method name as an array of the object and the method name, or a lambda) to every element in an array.

If you'd like me to elaborate, just ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would loop and use [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Here is a note from php.net that can be found on [preg_match() page.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#refsect1-function.preg-match-notes)

> Do not use preg_match() if you only
> want to check if one string is
> contained in another string. Use
> strpos() or strstr() instead as they
> will be faster.

Comment: Sure can.  strpos checks a string(haystack) for an occurrence of another string(needle) and will return the position of string(needle) if it is found or false if it is not found.  Using a foreach you can loop through your arrays and check the strings.  If you are only looking to find one occurrence in a set then you can break out of the loop after finding the first one.  The structure and the end logic will really depend on how you need to manipulate the data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I prefer the `serialize()` method.

Comment: serialize is great and would still work with strpos and as I noted in my answer strpos is faster than preg_match.

Comment: Thanks will switch to strpos.

Answer (score 0):

array_map and preg_match

```
$example_array[] = array(
    'host'      => 'google.com',
    'type'      => 'NS',
    'target'    => 'ns2.google.com',
    'class'     => 'IN',
    'ttl'       => 112756
);

$example_array[] = array(
    'host'      => 'google.com',
    'type'      => 'NS',
    'target'    => 'ns1.google.com',
    'class'     => 'IN',
    'ttl'       => 112756
); 

$example_array[] = array(
    'host'      => 'yahoo.com',
    'type'      => 'NS',
    'target'    => 'ns1.yahoo.com',
    'class'     => 'IN',
    'ttl'       => 112756
);
```

if you do a print_r() on the $example_array, this is how the array structure looks like:

```
echo print_r($example_array,true)."\n";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => google.com
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns2.google.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 112756
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [host] => google.com
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns1.google.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 112756
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [host] => yahoo.com
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns1.yahoo.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 112756
        )

)
```

Functions

```
function look4($haystack, $needle = 'google') {
    return preg_match("/$needle/i", $haystack);
}

// instead of $example_array use your array here
foreach($example_array as $sub_array) {
    $results = array_map("look4", $sub_array);
    print_r($results);
}
```

Results (the values of 0 (zero) are a false match, the values of 1 (one) are a true match):

```
Array
(
    [host] => 1
    [type] => 0
    [target] => 1
    [class] => 0
    [ttl] => 0
)
Array
(
    [host] => 1
    [type] => 0
    [target] => 1
    [class] => 0
    [ttl] => 0
)
Array
(
    [host] => 0
    [type] => 0
    [target] => 0
    [class] => 0
    [ttl] => 0
)
```

Comment: You re-wrote the format of my original array. So you're solution does work as is.

Comment: I rewrote the array to test, it's still in the same format and will work as is. Did you test it or just down vote me?

Comment: I tested it on my code. I don't have an variable called $mx_records, so that's why it broke and that's why I down voted you.

Comment: his solution is right. What he wrote is the same structure as you have, just written differently. $arr = array(array(), array()); is the same as $arr = array(); $arr[] = array(); $arr[] = array(); Please consider reading up on basic programming.

Comment: in the foreach loop replace the $example_array with your array variable

Comment: No, I was definitely getting an error with his code as $mx_records was not defined. I see that he has now changed that. Anyways, it still won't with my example above.

Comment: OMG, you do realize that it's an example and you would have to use the variable that contains your array values in my example right? I have added some more documentation to further explain. You really should know how to look at someones code and take away the logic of what they are trying to explain. I hope this clarifies the examples I have given you from your array structure you have given. It does show the results as you have wanted

Comment: And you sir, should learn to answer a question. You needlessly re-wrote my example code above causing the confusion. I agree, it's pretty minor, but this forum is all about accurate answers, and your's wasn't.

Anyways, my `serialize()` method is way less code. I'm going with that.

Comment: Wow, so if I just put: array_map and preg_match as my answer instead of taking your data given and making some example code for you to follow, Would have been better? What is inaccurate in my answer? The use of $mx_records or $example_array in my answer? You provided and array structure with NO VARIABLE OR CODE so I made one in my EXAMPLE CODE! Maybe you should ask a more ACCURATE QUESTION. I'm glad you found the answer you're looking but down voting a valid answer I don't get

Answer (score 0):

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function ($value) { return strpos($value['host'], 'google') !== false; });
```

`$filtered` will contain all entries where the `host` contains `"google"`. Requires PHP 5.3. Maybe use this with `preg_grep` instead of `strpos` as suggested by @Aaron Ray if you're interested in *any* field, not just the `host`.

---

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($value) { return strpos($value, 'google') !== false; });
```

This replaces all values with `true` or `false`, based on whether it contains the search term. Not sure what you'd use that for though... :)

---

```
$termExists = array_reduce($array, function ($found, $value) {
    return $found || preg_grep('/google/', $value);
});
```

This returns one boolean value whether the value exists at all in the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a much simpler way using `serialize()`.

```
$mymultiarrays = serialize($mymultiarrays);
echo preg_match( '/google/', $mymultiarrays;
```